# Is there a way to predict corrupted orphan inodes before the filesystem becomes read-only?

Tags: hard-disk, fsck

A few servers with 6 months old SSDs are going read-only. Some are going to rescue shell with the error `Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found`. I know I can run `fsck` and fix the issue but is there a way to find out before the corruption happens. Like gradual corruption before the system goes read only? This is Debian 11 using ext4 partition. The issue is that these are remote servers and if I reboot some will go into rescue shell and I can't do anything. I did try to run `fsck` on the mounted read-only filesystem and it fixed the issue. I just want to catch before the system goes read only.

Comment: Firstly, you can't fix the actual issue which is that the drives are failing. Once there are bad sectors for whatever reason, the only thing that can be done is to tell the OS not to write to them. The best course of action in this case is to create backups if you haven't already and replace the drives.

Comment: smartctl tests are passing so does that mean there no hardware failure? I can just reformat the same SSD with use it? This is filesystem level corruption.

Comment: SMART is not an all-knowing oracle: drives can sometimes fail in ways that are unanticipated by the programmer of the drive's SMART implementation. A dishonest manufacturer could make their drives return SMART data that either omits important information or is completely fake.

Comment: A possible cause of `...corrupted orphan linked list...` errors, assuming the underlying disk is indeed healthy, is uncontrolled shutdowns or system crashes. Are your systems losing power, or otherwise crashing frequently? If they are, that's probably the root cause of your problem.